# Adding ShareKit to existing iPad app gives strange syntax errors

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.2

I am trying to add ShareKit support to an existing iPad App. I got ShareKit code from http://getsharekit.com/. I added the ShareKit folder to the App per instructions and compiled it. Now I get syntax errors on previously working statements such as:

Statement in Constants.h file:
extern NSString * const kSupportURL;

Error:
Unknown type name 'NSString'

If I remove the ShareKit files it compiles and runs without any errors.

The project is being compiled under Xcode 4.2. Base SDK is "Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)". Target iOS Deployment target is "iOS 3.2". C Language Dialect is "C99 [-std=C99]"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you linked your frameworks, but that particular message would appear if you weren't linked to Foundation.framework or if you forgot to #import foundation